# Estimating the probability of a defective batch based on limited historical data

Tags: probability

I want to estimate the probability that the next batch 4 is defective, based on the results of incoming inspections of three previous batches. Batch 1 was rejected, batch 2 was accepted, and batch 3 was rejected. What mathematical methods or approaches can be used to calculate this probability? Are methods such as Markov chains or Bayesian inference suitable for this situation, and if so, how can I apply them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is quite vague.  If the batches are all the same size, you could just average the defective rates and use that.  If they are different sizes, you could take a weighted average.

Answer (score 0):

With this limited information a reasonable guess for the next batch is that it's rejected with probability $2/3$.  That's assuming the rejection is due to some actual problem with the batches, not pure luck.

If you have other information you could do better. For example, if you flip a coin three times and see HTH you would not expect heads next with probability $2/3$, because you have prior information - the coin is *probably* fair and this is just luck. If you get one tail in $100$ tosses you would change your thoughts about whether the coin is fair.

**Edit** in response to a comment:

Yes, a Markov chain is overkill here. For so few batches I would go with the probability of the next batch bad as the ratio of the number of bad batches over the number of batches. So it's 2/3 for the fourth batch. If that's bad the probability changes to 3/4 for the next one to be bad, If it's good the probability changes to 2/4=1/2. (This is actually Bayesian in philosophy: updating prior beliefs based on new evidence.) If over time the bad batches get rarer (because the supplier is fixing things?) you could go with a weighted average that counts recent data more heavily.

Comment: Okay, that is simpler than I expected. So, would a Markov chain be unnecessary? My assumption is: if the last batch from a specific supplier is defective, the likelihood of the next batch being defective is high, as there seems to be an issue in the production process. That's why a Markov chain seemed like a good choice to me.

Comment: Okay, if the batch amount is going to 200 in total per supplier, then is this method still appropriate?

Comment: My answer treats a batch as a single unit. If batches are large and rejection depends on some fraction of the batch the problem is more complex and you need to provide a lot more data.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. A random sample is taken from the batch, and the rejection is compared to the AQL standard. If it exceeds the standard, the entire batch is rejected. The AQL level is 0.15. The amount of units in a batch varies between 4 - 40 units.  For example we have the following batches inspected:  Batch 1 6,00 units
Batch 2 6,00 units
Batch 3 12,00 units
Batch 4 18,00 units
Batch 5 13,00 units
Batch 6 18,00 units
Batch 7 4,00 units
Batch 8 4,00 units
Batch 9 10,00 units
Batch 10 10,00 units
Batch 11 4,00 
Batch 12 7,00
Batch 13 7,00
Batch 14 38,00
Batch 15 4,00

Comment: That's a lot more data, which makes the problem more interesting, more doable, and beyond my pay grade. I could figure it out but that would take more time than I care to commit. You could consider asking on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ - post all the data. You probably want a range of predictions of the batch failure probability, along with the costs of over or underestimating the probability.